# Attribution in academia

Tags: ethics

I'm working in a university IT project as a researcher. I'm not pursuing a Ph.D. but rather working as a software developer there, designing and implementing software for the project. I learn a lot and am able to evaluate new technologies what I really enjoy. My work however is considered irrelevant compared to writing papers and project proposals.

When presenting in front of project partners and potential new project partners my work is always shown as it is the only tangible result of the project (there hasn't even been a paper in over a year by other colleagues). Sometimes my work is presented without me and I'm unclear in which context that happens and whether my name is mentioned or not.

Recently most colleagues of the project announced that they will jump ship and switch to a new project which is seen as the successor. I wasn't considered for the project and also not involved in the planning process. I'm staying in the old project which ends in about five months without having a new one, but was asked to present my work in front of an important company that is a potential sponsor of the successor project next week. I think I was asked to present because the company is comming to the same office where I'm working and they wouldn't get away presenting my work whithout me noticing.

I'm unsure how to handle the situation. It could be a chance for me to get important contacts for a potential new project. On the other hand I feel used and left behind. Is it normal to present someone else's work without permission? How to protect against this behaviour? Legally the software belongs to the university.

Comment: I'm not clear about what "behavior" you object to. Asking you to present? Not including you in the new project? Both? Something else?

Comment: I think it's weird to throw someone out of the window and at the same time asking for a favor. The "behaviour" question refers to the fact that my work got presented without my consent and I'm not sure how I can make sure that it is not happening again.

Comment: You said you were "asked to present my work in front of an important company", not that someone else did without your consent. Still confused. Sorry.

Comment: @user112529 you probably have a PI/line manager, did you talk to them? You should at least let them know that you're looking for a job after this one, and ask if there's anything for you in the new project. They might mistakenly assume that you're not interested if you don't say anything.

Comment: Can you clarify your specific questions?